# Entity Framework Associate update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity framework and struggling to find a solution for the following. I've 3 different tables - Admin, AdminReport and Reports. Admin is the admin details of an application, Admin Report is the report details which is owned by the specific admin. Reports is the reference table that contains the reference data of the reports.

[image: Table Relationship]

Now, When I add these tables, Admin and Report tables are added as entity but AdminReport is added as Association.

I'm in a situation, where I need to delete or insert records into Admin Report but whenever I do something, Entity Framework tries to update my reference table "Report". Code as below:

```
 public void UpdateAdminDetails(List<AdminDetails> AdminListtoUpdate)
  {

  foreach(var admin in AdminListtoUpdate )
  {
  var updateAdmin = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(item => item.adminId == admin.AdminId && !admin.IsNew);


                    updateAdmin.IsAdmin = admin.IsAdmin;
                   updateAdmin.PersonId = admin.PersonId;

// User on the front end can remove few reports associated with the admin

                    var AdminReportIDsListToDelete = admin.AdminReport.Select(d => d.AdminReportId).ToList();
                    var itemsToDelete = updateAdmin.AdminReports.Where(d => !AdminReportIDsListToDelete.Contains(d.AdminReportId)).ToList();
                    foreach (var itemtoDelete in itemsToDelete)
                       admin.AdminReport.Remove(itemtoDelete);

// User on the front end can add new reports to the admin.           
                   var AdminReportIDsListToCreate = updateAdmin.AdminReports.Select(c => c.AdminReportId).ToList();
                   var itemsToCreate = admin.AdminReports.Where(c => !AdminReportIDsListToCreate.Contains(c.AdminReportId)).ToList();
                    updateAdmin.AdminReports.AddRange(itemsToCreate);
                   db.saveChanges();
                   }
                   }
```

But, I'm getting an error message stating that it cannot insert duplicate records to the reports table.

Request your help to resolve this query. Thanks.

Comment: This SO question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489695/how-to-remove-relationship-between-two-entities

Comment: Thanks much Jlvaquero... It solved my issue with removing the existing reports. But the issue with Adding reports still remain an issue.

Comment: Tried few other options but no luck at all...  It might look weird but I'm running out of options and I'm struggling to  find a solution for the same. dbContext.EmployerAdmins.Attach(updateAdmin);
                            dbContext.Entry(updateAdmin).Entity.EmployerAdminReports.Add(empAdmin.EmployerAdminReport.SingleOrDefault(item => item.EmployerAdminReportId == addItem));

Comment: Update is like delete. Forget about AdminReport relation. Just `adminToUpdate.ReportList.Add(newReport)`.

Comment: Thanks Jlvaquero... I resolved the issue. I've detailed the solution in my answer. Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I did the following to update the association without letting entity framework updating the reference table.

```
foreach(var itemToCreate in itemsToCreate)

 updateAdmin.AdminReports.Add(db.Report.SingleorDefault(item=>item.ReportId == itemToCreate.ReportId));
```

Through this simple statement I'm telling entity framework to update the association with the record that it has in the reference table "Report". It works sweet and the associated table gets updated.

Comment: Is there any reason why `updateAdmin.Reports.Add(existingReport)` does not work? Because touching relation tables in your entities bypass ORS spirit.

Comment: jlvaquero -  updateAdmin.Reports.Add(newReport) tries to add a new record in report table. For some reasons, it recognises newReport (though the type of newReport is same as Reports) as a new Report that needs to be added. I got it resolved when I picked the existing report from the reports table and add a reference to the adminReport.